# Reason for Tegmark's CUH

Tags: physics, model-theory, incompleteness

Apart from the (well fundamented) critics to Tegmark's Mathematical Universe Hypothesis ( https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.0646 ) I´d like to know how he justifies the assumption of the Computable Universe Hypothesis.

It seems that it uses it to avoid Godel incompleteness but I can´t find in the cited paper  where he  explains why he assumes it.

In fact, in his book "Our Mathematical Universe" he says (bold is mine):

> A first concern about the CUH is that it my sound like a surrender to
>   philosophical high ground, effectively conceding that athough all
>   possible mathematical structures are "out there", some have privileged
>   status. **However my guess is CUH turns out to be correct, it will be instead be because the rest of the mathematical landscape was mere illusion**, fundamentally undefined and simply not existing in any meaningful sense

So does anybody know the reason for Tegmark´s CUH assumption?